# UIView/CALayer bulk loading to improve rendering

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a view that has many subviews and sublayers that are built up from a background thread using NSOperation. Then I invoked back to the main thread when adding them to the UIView that is already being displayed. When everything is done rendering, performance and responsiveness is great. However, the main thread seems to be taking a very long time to do the initial render of my views, causing performance issues while the initial render is taking place.

I was able to get around this performance issue if my NSOperation added the subviews/sublayers to a currently visible UIView, but it would not appear until it was tapped on. Calling the setNeedsDisplay method did not resolve this issue.

I am wondering if their is a way to tell the main thread that I am adding a bunch of views so that it knows to do this more optimally? Somthing similar to an addSubviewRange instead of addSubview?